# python3 os.system() fails with error sh: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I am trying to run this using python3 
`system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (password, "date > " + file_path))`

but getting this as error
`sh: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected`

Comment: `subprocess.Popen('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (password, "date > " + file_path),stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`

Comment: This worked for me perfectly Thanks.

Comment: please up vote and mark as correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibly unrelated problem is that you aren't properly quoting the input and output the variables in the command.

```
system('echo "%s"|sudo -S "%s"' % (password, "date > " + file_path))
```

However, for all legal filenames as filenames. I would recommend using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`, leaving the shell out of the process altogether:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (password, "date > " + file_path), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```